# Display certain number of letters

Tags: swift

I have a word that is being displayed into a label. Could I program it, where it will only show the last 2 characters of the word, or the the first 3 only?  How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is confusing and your title is different. Do you want to show the last two letters of the word? Or do you have a string with many words and you want to show only the last two words?

Comment: I have a string, with one word. I want to be able to show the last few letters or the first few letters.

Answer (score 2):

Swift's string APIs can be a little confusing. You get access to the characters of a string via its `characters` property, on which you can then use `prefix()` or `suffix()` to get the substring you want. That subset of characters needs to be converted back to a `String`:

```
let str = "Hello, world!"

// first three characters:
let prefixSubstring = String(str.characters.prefix(3))

// last two characters:
let suffixSubstring = String(str.characters.suffix(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is definitely confusing working with String indexing in Swift and they have changed a little bit from Swift 1 to 2 making googling a bit of a challenge but it can actually be quite simple once you get a hang of the methods. You basically need to make it into a two-step process:

1) Find the index you need
2) Advance from there

For example:

```
let sampleString = "HelloWorld"
let lastThreeindex = sampleString.endIndex.advancedBy(-3)
sampleString.substringFromIndex(lastThreeindex) //prints rld

let secondIndex = sampleString.startIndex.advancedBy(2)
sampleString.substringToIndex(secondIndex) //prints He
```