# Why do I need the string to determine the index for the Nth character?

Tags: swift, string, substring

I'd like to get a substring of a string that is just the first N characters. (10, for example).

But the string is the generated output of a function.

I'd like to do it like this...

```
let string = someInputString
    .someGeneratorFunctionThatReturnsAString()
    .substring(to: 10)
```

But I can't do this. Because the index in the substring function needs the string itself to determine where the 10th character is.

- First question... why is this the case?
- Second question... how can I get a substring like this without needing the original string to get the index.

Comment: From what I've gatered, it's more or less like this: Strings in Swift are internally stored as UTF-8, so random access is not possible (characters are of variable byte length), so there's this thing called "indices" that you create form a specific string and modify by advancing or going back an integer number of places (sequentially), and they work only for that string.

Comment: @NicolasMiari ah, that makes sense. Add it as an answer :D

Comment: Thanks, but my knowledge is quite shallow and might be slightly off. I'll leave the honour to someone else. In the mean time, you can check out this link: https://oleb.net/blog/2016/08/swift-3-strings/

Comment: @NicolasMiari: Actually strings use internally either ASCII or UTF-16, but that is an implementation detail and might change in the future.

Comment: @MartinR Alright, UTF-16 too is variable length, right? I wonder how come accessing the n-th character was straightforward in Objective-C... Must study this

Comment: @NicolasMiari: Not really. But a `Character` is an "extended grapheme cluster" and consists of one or many unicode scalars.

Comment: @Fogmeister:  Here is a simple solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32984213/1187415.

Comment: @Fogmeister See? I was talking out of my a** :-) Listen to the people who know!

Comment: More helpers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language.

Comment: ... on the other hand, I am not a fan of adding all these extensions just to "make it work with integer indices", that can be a performance bottleneck. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371929/slow-swift-string-performance for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just maybe understand your question wrong but nevertheless here you can substring easily:

```
extension String {
    func substring(to: Int) -> String? {
        return self.substring(to: self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: to))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I created an extension like this also. Just wondered about why it required the string. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

See [Gunhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807110/gunhan)'s answer to question 2.

For question 1:

**Long Answer**: Basically, in Swift, the [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) protocol (which types like Array and String adopt) specifies performance criteria. Most notably, the start and end indices of a collection must be accessible in *O*(1) time. This goes for subscript access of elements as well (see text under **Expected Performance** heading on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection).

Indices are memory addresses that point to either another reference or value type. For string, the indices point to `Character` struct values. While the *value* of the characters in the strings `let x = "hello"` and `let y = "hello"` might be the same, the constants `x` and `y` are different memory addresses and so are the indices that point to their respective `Character` struct values. So, you cannot get the substring `"llo"` from `x` and the substring `"llo"` from `y` using the same indices... that would make no sense, because the indices you would use would be specific memory addresses to only of those variables.

Architecturally, there are three entities having interplay here:

`String |--hasIndicesOfType--> String.Index |--whichPointTo--> Character`

(Side note: Here, `Index` is an `associatedtype` on `String`, which is why you see the notation `String.Index` if you were to, say, log one of these to the Xcode console).

**In a nutshell**: the answer to *why* the function needs the string itself is because indices of a string are memory addresses to characters of the string. `String` conforms to `Collection` to get *O*(1) performance on access to `String`'s elements. Thus, the indices. Because indices are memory addresses, they only work on a given object (reference type) - which is why generic access to characters of a string only work for one string (i.e. you cannot access string A's elements with memory addresses to string B's characters... that doesn't make sense.)

**In a super tiny nutshell**: because `String` conforms to `Collection`.

Some helpful tutorial-ish code:

- [Struct references](http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/references/)
- [Struct references gist](https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/3423e722d1da4e8cce7cfdf85f026ef7)
- [Preview of *Advanced Swift* book](https://www.objc.io/books/advanced-swift/preview/) (highly recommend this book)

**Teleology**: Apparent end-goal-reasoning (aka [teleological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) analysis) behind *why* `String` is the way it is in Swift:

Contributors to the language preferred optimizing [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) over [space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE).